# In Sql server, what is the query to get the details of collation for a database and columns in the tables

Tags: sql-server, collation

Would like to know exact query to fetch the collation details on database level and also for each column in the table in the Sql Server.

Please provide your response.

Comment: Please provide your attempt

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230914.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For database level

```
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases where database_id = db_id()
```

For all table columns, you can use following

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'SELECT ''?'', name, collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id(''?'')'
```

For [sp_MSForEachTable](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-exec-sp_msforeachdb-sp_msforeachtable-example-tsql-code.aspx) syntax and examples please refer to referenced link

Comment: Thanks alot providing your response.

I found other queries, for database level - "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')"
                       for table columns - "select column_name, collation_name from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME = <TableName>"   

Please, let me know your views on these queries.

Comment: Hi user3355153, thanks for info. Information_Schema provides more data easier to query. select table_name, column_name, collation_name from information_schema.columns